# .vbs script to change Connection Specific DNS suffix

Tags: vbscript, dns, cmd, command

I'm looking for a way to have this .vbs file add a connection specific DNS suffix for an Ethernet Adaptor with the known name of LAN

The code forms past of a small shell script that:

1. Changes the primary DNS Suffix
2. Flushes the DNS
3. Checks the IP details  to make sure everything had held
4. Changes a startup type or a service
5. Starts said service
6. Pings a know server to ensure network connectivity

Cant seem to find any code thats viable to make the first step work. currently I have :

```
 'add dns

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient"
oReg.CreateKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath
strValueName = "AppendToMultiLabelName"
'Enabled
strValue = "mysuffix.com"
oReg.SetStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strKeyPath,strValueName,strValue


'flush dns

set shell = createobject("wscript.shell") 
shell.run("ipconfig /flushdns")
Wscript.echo "DNS Flushed."


'check DNS

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objScriptExec = objShell.Exec("ipconfig /all")
strIpConfig = objScriptExec.StdOut.ReadAll
WScript.Echo strIpConfig


'start McAfee

strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colServiceList = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
    ("Select * from Win32_Service where Name = 'enterceptAgent'")

For Each objService in colServiceList
    If objService.State = "Stopped" Then
        objService.StartService()
        Wscript.Sleep 5000
        Wscript.Echo "McAfee Started"
    Else
        Wscript.Echo "McAfee already running"
        Wscript.Sleep 5000
    End If
    errReturnCode = objService.ChangeStartMode("automatic")   
Next

'network test

set shell = createobject("wscript.shell") 
shell.run("ping pmo2 -t")
```

Cheers

Comment: IMHO, there are at least two registry placements for _Primary DNS Suffix_ settings; I'm not sure about it's preference (a guestion for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) rather): key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Paramaters`, values `Domain` and `SearchList`; and key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\DNSClient `, value `NV PrimaryDnsSuffix`. Any registry manipulations may require a restart to apply...

Comment: thanks JosefZ, the key i found to manipulate is in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\Tcpip\Parameters\Adapters but required the correct GUID to be selected which means its easier to do it manually rather than with a script, But I shall look into your suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (configures to the correct GUID, see `objNetCard.SettingID` property):

```
option explicit
'On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0
Dim strResult: strResult = Wscript.ScriptName

Dim strComputer, objWMIService, colNetCards, objNetCard
strComputer = "." 
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _ 
    & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

Set colNetCards = objWMIService.ExecQuery _ 
    ("Select * From Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration Where IPEnabled = True") 

For Each objNetCard in colNetCards
  strResult = strResult _
    & vbNewLine & objNetCard.Caption & vbTab & "'" & objNetCard.DNSDomain & "'" & vbTab & CBool( IsEmpty( objNetCard.DNSDomain)) & vbTab & CBool( IsNull( objNetCard.DNSDomain))
  strResult = strResult _
    & vbNewLine & objNetCard.SetDNSDomain("mysuffix.com") 
''    strResult = strResult & vbNewLine & objNetCard.SetDNSSuffixSearchOrder("mysuffix.com") 

Next 
'strResult = strResult & vbNewLine

Wscript.Echo strResult
```

See [SetDNSDomain method return codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393294(v=vs.85).aspx)